# GPL Ghostscript 9.53.3: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1 when trying to draw pspicture inside tabular environment

Tags: errors, plot, ghostscript, auto-pst-pdf

Here is the code that is giving me this problem. Basically I'm trying to render inside a grid a couple of pictures plotting the beta probability density function for different values of the parameters .

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\usepackage{pst-func, pst-plot}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}

\psset{xunit=6cm, yunit=2cm}
\begin{tabular}{c@{\hspace{1.5cm}}c}
    $\text{Figura 1}.\quad \alpha_t=\alpha_h = 0.5$ & $\text{Figura 2}.\quad \alpha_t=\alpha_h = 1$\\[-0.5em]
    \begin{pspicture*}(-1,-1)(1.1,3.1)
    \psaxes[linecolor=black, tickcolor=black, ticksize=3pt -3pt, ticks=all, tickstyle=bottom, Dx=0.1, Dy=0.5, labelFontSize=\scriptstyle]{-}(0,0)(1.005,3.005)
    \psBetaDist[linecolor=red, alpha=0.5, beta=0.5]{0.005}{0.995}
    \end{pspicture*} &
    \begin{pspicture*}(-1,-1)(1.1,3.1)
    \psaxes[linecolor=black, tickcolor=black, ticksize=3pt -3pt, ticks=all, tickstyle=bottom, Dx=0.1, Dy=0.5, labelFontSize=\scriptstyle]{-}(0,0)(1.005,3.005)
    \psBetaDist[linecolor=red, alpha=1, beta=1]{0.005}{0.995}
    \end{pspicture*}\\
    $\text{Figura 3}.\quad \alpha_t=\alpha_h = 4$ & $\text{Figura 4}.\quad \alpha_t=\alpha_h = 7.5$\\[-0.5em]
    \begin{pspicture*}(-1,-1)(1.1,3.1)
    \psaxes[linecolor=black, tickcolor=black, ticksize=3pt -3pt, ticks=all, tickstyle=bottom, Dx=0.1, Dy=0.5, labelFontSize=\scriptstyle]{-}(0,0)(1.005,3.005)
    \psBetaDist[linecolor=red, alpha=4, beta=4]{0.005}{0.995}
    \end{pspicture*} &
    \begin{pspicture*}(-1,-1)(1.1,3.1)
    \psaxes[linecolor=black, tickcolor=black, ticksize=3pt -3pt, ticks=all, tickstyle=bottom, Dx=0.1, Dy=0.5, labelFontSize=\scriptstyle]{-}(0,0)(1.005,3.005)
    \psBetaDist[linecolor=red, alpha=7.5, beta=7.5]{0.005}{0.995}
    \end{pspicture*} \\
    $\text{Figura 5}.\quad \alpha_h= 7, \alpha_t = 3$\\[-0.5em]
    \begin{pspicture*}(-1,-1)(1.1,3.1)
    \psaxes[linecolor=black, tickcolor=black, ticksize=3pt -3pt, ticks=all, tickstyle=bottom, Dx=0.1, Dy=0.5, labelFontSize=\scriptstyle]{-}(0,0)(1.005,3.005)
    \psBetaDist[linecolor=red, alpha=7, beta=3]{0.005}{0.995}
    \end{pspicture*}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

On my laptop it compiles correctly with pdflatex + auto-pst-pdf while on my desktop it doesn't work independently of what I'm running, I tried the same as I did on my laptop and to use XeLaTeX, I even tried running it with

```
pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode --shell-escape %.tex
```

but I'm still out of luck. Every time I compile now all I get is a bunch of errors like this:

```
GPL Ghostscript 9.53.3: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
```

Any idea for possible fixes? TIA.

Comment: it doesn't make much sense to run auto-pst-pdf on a standalone picture. Why don't you use simply latex+dvips+ps2pdf? (and remove this `\noindent\\ ` )

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Actually I used a standalone document class in the code just to have a minimal (supposed to be) working example. The actual code has \documentclass[12pt]{book} and there's stuff below the tabular environment, that's why there's a \noindent\\ after...

Comment: standalone isn't a good class to debug an error. That is a very complex class with lots of side effects. And the noindent doesn't make sense.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: I'm sorry for being ignorant then, feel free to make any edit that you think would help isolating the problem. Though, I must say that I believe the issue is not within the code itself, else it shouldn't have compiled in my laptop either...

Comment: no I won't edit your question. It is your problem. But believe me: make an example as short as possible and without standalone. Use book or article.

Comment: @Bafforasta: Compiling with `xelatex`  shows no problem here – just an `overfull hbox` warning.

Comment: @Bernard: I tried that already but it doesn't work for me, same error as before. Also, even if I remove everything else and leave an empty pspicture I still get that Ghostscript error.

Comment: @Bafforasta: Is your distribution up-to-date?

Comment: @Bernard: I'm using TexLive 2020 on my laptop and TexLive 2021 on my desktop. Ironically on the older distribution it works fine while on the newest it throws the error in the title.

Comment: Mmm… I can't really compile, since I am under MiKTeX. But also, I have an independent Ghostscript distribution installed (9.54.0). I wonder whether xelatex uses  MiKTeX's ghostscript, or the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I uninstalled Texlive 2021 and Texlive 2020 from my PC and got myself a fresh install for Texlive 2020, and now it finally works if I compile the code using XeLaTeX under TexStudio. While I know this is not a fix but just a workaround, this solved my problem and you might take in consideration to do it as well if you're facing my same error.

Answer (score 0):

You corrected file (i.e., using the book document class) typesets fine if you first change the size to `\psset{xunit=3cm, yunit=1cm}` to fit on a page, and ii)typeset using latex rather than pdflatex so there is no need to use auto-pst-pdf AND MOST IMPORTANT iii)make sure to to run ps2pdf using the
-dALLOWPSTRANSPARENCY option for Ghostscript 3.53.

Comment: unfortunately I need to use pdflatex as I have .png images somewhere else in my code... also using lower xunit and yunit will make the plot harder to see.

Comment: Note: using auto-pst-pdf creates a file with all the pictures and then runs it through latex->dvips->ps2pdf but, I'm pretty sure, it doesn't do transparency correctly so fails. Why not create pdfs of your pictures using latex, etc., correctly and then including them in your main pdflatex compiled document.

Comment: I mean, it's not unreasonable cause I can create the pdf using my laptop but all of this is driving me insane! If it compiles on my laptop then it must work on my desktop, too.

Also, I just reset to default config my TexStudio and added dALLOWPSTRANSPARENCY option to ps2pdf, switched to XeLaTeX with --shell-escape. Now it compiles with no error but in the picture both the axis and the plot are not showing (like if they were transparent indeed)...

Comment: Are you using an updated TeX Live 2021? If so use `xelatex -output-driver="xdvipdfmx -i dvipdfmx-unsafe.cfg -q -E" -synctex=1 yourfile.tex` if you want to typeset with xelatex.

Comment: I tried with it but the situation is still the same, i.e. transparent axis and plot... unfortunately it didn't fix.

Comment: @herb-schulz Is it possible to configure the `xelatex -output-driver="xdvipdfmx -i dvipdfmx-unsafe.cfg -q -E" -synctex=1 yourfile.tex` option somewhere in config files that I do not have to remember this option? Thanks!